# Return type error?

Tags: java, types, return

I am doing a Java exercise for my class and encountered an error. It says "incompatible types: unexpected return value". It would also be nice if someone could check if I am doing this code right. My instructions were to create a varaiable maxValue that is to be intialized to the first element. Then I have to compare the element that maxValue stores with another element in my list. And if an element in the array is larger than the one stored in maxValue, it is suppose to store/update maxValue with the larger element.

```
public class MyArray
  {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   int[] ArrayLargestElement = {
       45, 38, 27, 
       46, 81, 72,
       56, 61, 20,
       48, 76, 91, 
       57, 35, 78
    };
   int maxValue = ArrayLargestElement[0]
   for (int i=0; i<ArrayLargestElement.length; i++) {
       if (maxValue  > ArrayLargestElement[i]) {
           maxValue = ArrayLargestElement[i];
        }
   }
   return maxValue;    
  } 
}
```

Comment: `public static void main()` doesn't have return value!

Comment: Why do you want to return value from main() ?

Answer (score 0):

`main()` is static void. It can't return `maxValue`. I think you wanted to `print` it.

```
// return maxValue;    
System.out.printf("maxValue = %d%n", maxValue);
```

But perhaps you were trying to extract that to a method like

```
public static int getLargestValue(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        max = Integer.max(max, arr[i]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then you could call it in `main()` like

```
public static int getLargestValue(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        max = Integer.max(max, arr[i]);
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 45, 38, 27, 46, 81, 72, 56, 61, 20, 48, 76, 91, 57, 35,
            78 };
    System.out.println(getLargestValue(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not return value in  `void Main()` function .
        write function to return a value.

```
public static int getmax(int max[])
   {
       int maxValue = max[0]
   for (int i=0; i<max.length; i++) 
    {
   if (maxValue  > max[i]) 
      {
       maxValue = max[i];
      }
    }
   return maxValue; 
  }
```

call a function in `main`

```
public class MyArray
  {
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     int[] ArrayLargestElement = {
      45, 38, 27, 
      46, 81, 72,
      56, 61, 20,
      48, 76, 91, 
      57, 35, 78
     };
     System.out.print("Maximum value in ArrayList"+getmax(ArrayLargestElement));
  }
     /*write your function here */
}
```

Comment: `main()`, you mean? Case matters.

Answer (score 0):

A main() is by nature, a void method. It is not meant to return a value. You could, however, use System.out.println to display your maxValue to the console. Otherwise, I would suggest writing a method which actually would return a max value for you, like one of the methods listed above. Hope this helped!